# Can't access docker container on virtualbox from Internet

Tags: virtualbox, docker-for-windows

I have ToolBox installed on Windows 10.
Have created machine, and Nginx container, opened outside on port 8000.

[image]

Docker machine's IP is `192.168.99.100`, container's IP is `172.17.0.2`.
I can access Nginx from Windows as `192.168.99.100:8000`. Even more, I can access from Windows host directly to `172.17.0.2:80`. Also I can access Internet from inside the container.

At all the configuration is as following:

```
Container (Nginx)           Docker Host (VirtualBox)            Host (Windows 10)                                                     Router
172.17.0.2:80 <-----------> 172.17.0.1 (docker0)
                            10.0.2.15 (eth0)
                            192.168.99.100:8000 (eth1) <------> 192.168.99.1 (Ethernet 2, VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter)
                                                                192.168.1.3 (Ethernet, Intel Hardware Adapter) <--------------------> 192.168.1.1
                                                                                                                                      <Internet static IP address> <-----------> Provider
```

The problem is that I can't connect Nginx ouside of Windows host. Tried `telnet 192.168.1.3 8000` from router - connection refused.
I have no any antivirus on Windows machine, and firewal is switched off.

Answer (score 7):

After a time have fount solution myself :)

```
VirtualBox -> Machine settings -> Network -> Adapter 1 (NAT) -> Advanced, Port Forwarding
```

Add rule like `http` on the screenshot:

[image]

Rule `ssh` has been automatically added by `docker-machine create`.
The last quesion is how to add `http` rule automatically when docker creates container with ports exposed.

Comment: Did you have DHCP for NAT in Virtual Box configurations? How did you configure Network adapter? Because if I run docker-machine, I see ["Waiting for an IP..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54203014/8370915) and nothing happens. But your answer will be very helpful if you add more details for configurations of Virtual Box. I'm using Virtual Box 6.0 and Linux Mint 19. And I've [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57647957/8370915) successfully docker-machine on Linux system.

Answer (score -1):

Your title is internet, but your solution prefer you mean LAN.

this code do the similar trick:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectaddress=192.168.99.100 connectport=8000 protocol=tcp
```